I can't retrieve User-Generated Content (UGC) using the Member Data Portability (Member) Product REST API from LinkedIn
I'm developing a Python script to fetch information about my most recent five posts using the LinkedIn API's Member Data Portability (Member) Product.
Although I am successfully retrieving some data, it isn't exactly what I need.
Here are the issues I'm encountering:

The data I receive isn't current; the dates are significantly older than today's date.

The response includes all types of activities (such as likes and invitations), but I'm specifically interested in retrieving only my own content (ugcPosts).


I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions you could provide.
Thank you!
import json
import requests

# client_id = "_secret_"
# client_secret = "_secret_"

access_token = "_secret_"

api_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/memberChangeLogs?q=memberAndApplication"

headers = {"LinkedIn-Version": "202312", "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

payload = {"count" : 5, "resourceName" : "ugcPosts" , "sortBy" : "LAST_MODIFIED"}

response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params = payload)
data = json.loads(response.text)

print(data)

I get all kinds of activities (likes, invitations) that are not what I need.
Things I tried (and didn't work):

Passing the startTime as the current time (in epochs) -- to get the latest acitivity at least

Running the requests.get() in a loop until I get a ugcPosts (resourceName) -- doesn't working since there is a limit to the number of requests to the API



I have not worked on LinkedIn API at all, but looking over their API docs, you might be better served using the Content API instead?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/contentapi-migration-guide?view=li-lms-2024-04#ugcposts-api--posts-api
It seems like the Members Data API is meant for data archival & have no guarantees around timeliness.
